# How to substitute correctly in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this equation:

```
max_rep = (kg * rep * 0.0333) + kg
```

By providing the value of `max_rep` and `rep` I want to find the value of `kg`, but I'm doing something wrong.

What I have tried:

```
max_rep = 70
rep = 10
```

So,

```
70 = (kg * 10 * 0.0333) + kg
70 = (kg * 0.333) + kg
70/0.333 = 2kg
210.21/2 = kg
~105 = kg
```

This isn't correct though. Where is my mistake?

Probably a VERY easy equation substitution question for everyone in here, but I would appreciate an explanation to any answer so I can learn from my mistake.

Comment: Third lane of solution is false.

Comment: You should divide by $2.333$, not by $0.333$

Comment: @openspace why $2.333$?

Comment: Because of, if you divide by $0,333$, there is $\frac{1333}{333}$ on right side, not $2$. Keep calm, dude

Comment: sry, $1,333$ exactly

Comment: That line should say `kg/0.333 = kg + kg/0.333`, which is to say, you only divided the *first term* by 0.333, not the entire right side.

Comment: @user1070241 yes, pjs36 is right

Comment: @openspace I'm calm. Please don't make unnecessary comments like that.

Comment: @user1070241 sorry , I just want best for you

Comment: @openspace, apologies I think I misunderstood the way you said it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is:

max_rep = (kg * rep * 0.0333) + kg

You know max_rep and rep values.

You want to know kg.

We do this:

max_rep =kg[( rep * 0.0333) + 1]

kg=max_rep/[( rep * 0.0333) + 1] as long as rep is not zero.

The problem you had was moving from this step:

70 = (kg * 0.333) + kg         ----(1)

To get this *(not correct):*

70/0.333 = 2kg

From (1),

70 = kg [ (1 * 0.333) + 1 ]

Which leads to:

kg= 70/[ (1 * 0.333) + 1 ]

**EDIT** (to answer you question in the comment)

OK, the concept of factoring may not be clear for you. look at the following example: $x=a+b$.

Let us take out k from the R.H.S to get this means we divide each member separated by + or - sign by $k$ and multiply the entire R.H.S by $k$

$x = k [\frac{a}{k}+\frac{b}{k}]$.

In your case:

70 = (kg * 0.333) + kg

factor  'kg' out from R.H.S to get:

kg * [(kg * 0.333) + kg]/kg ]

Which becomes:

kg * [(kg * 0.333)/kg + (kg/kg)]

in the above step kg/kg = 1 (that answers your question in the comment)

kg * [(1 * 0.333) + 1] = kg * 1.333

Comment: @pjs36, many thanks for the gentle correction. Edited.

Comment: Thank you it works. I don't understand why you are adding 1 on the right side though ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like this. You made a mistake when you divided only 70 with 0.333. You must always divide every number when you divide.

max_rep = 70

rep = 10

max_rep = (kg * rep * 0.0333) + kg

70 = (kg * 10 * 0.0333) + kg

70 = (kg * 0.333) + kg

70 = 0.333kg + kg

70 = kg(0.333 + 1)

70 = kg x 1.333

kg = 70 / 1.333

kg = approximately 52.5